# Finding significant peaks with MATLAB's findpeaks()

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I'm using MATLAB's findpeaks function to quickly identify peaks in data:

[image: Full signal]

You'll notice the peak on the second negative-sloping section, magnified here:

[image: Magnified false peak]

This peak is a known artifact of the measurement, and I'd like to exclude it. I have many such data, some with the artifact and some without, so I'd like an automated way to exclude them when encountered. What settings do I need to adjust in findpeaks to remove these pseudo-peaks? I've experimented with 'MinPeakProminence', 'Threshold', and 'MinPeakWidth' to no avail. Although it may not be obvious from the pictures, this data has thousands of data points, so the nearest neighbors of any point are very similar (look at the x-axis scale).

Comment: Filter the data, repeat.

Comment: My concern is since I'm very sensitive to the peak location, I don't want to even slightly modify it with a filter.

Comment: @Pete: What didn't work about `'MinPeakProminence'` or `'MinPeakWidth'`? Seems like a minimum peak prominence of even 0.1 would easily catch that example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First smooth the data using a median filter: `y = medfilt1(x)` and then apply find peaks on it `z = findpeaks(y)`

Alternatively, find the peaks: `[pks,locs] = findpeaks(data)` , then go over each of the peaks, and see if it is the absolute maximum in its neighborhood:

```
span = 10;%play with this number
counter = 0
for ii = 1:length(pks)
   if pks(ii) == max(data(locs(ii)-span:locs(ii)+span))
      counter = counter + 1;
      new_pks[counter]  = pks[ii];
      new_locs[counter] = locs[ii];
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have R2014b or later, try checking out the [`MinPeakProminence` name-value pair](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html#input_argument_d0e61186).  This can help you select peaks that are more prominent (a relative measure of how much they stand out) as opposed to selecting them by absolute value.